# Table's columns in stored procedure are not up to date

Tags: sql, sql-server, intellisense

I have trouble using a stored procedure in SQL Server. I switched datatype of a table from `nvarchar` to `sql_variant` so all my data are now stored as bit, but SQL Server still that my value datatype is `NVarchar`, as you can see in this screenshot:

[image: column of intellisense are not fresh]

As is, the `date` column is not up to either, either, still `datetime` instead of `datetimeoffset`

To switch, I used the schema of my database.

How can I fix it all ?

Comment: Did you try closing and re-opening SSMS?

Comment: Just use CTRL+SHIFT+R

Comment: If all your data is a bit why are you using sql variant?

Comment: @SeanLange Because this may be a int, a float etc

Comment: Yes I understand how the sql_variant datatype works but you said everything is a bit. FWIW, the sql_variant is a nightmare to work with. You always have to cast/convert it to the datatype you want. But that is a different topic entirely. You might want to take a read of this article. https://sqlblog.org/2009/10/12/bad-habits-to-kick-choosing-the-wrong-data-type Look specifically at the section discussing sql_variant.

Comment: @SeanLange Yes, for this sensor, but in this table, i will store multiple sensors, and some of values could be a int or a double for example. So for my case, how can i do otherwise ?

Comment: Well you wouldn't want to use double or float. But you could certainly store either as a numeric.

Comment: Well yes, that's true, i will do it, thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Refresh your local intellisense cache via the Edit/Intellisense menu.

Answer (score 0):

I think you should refresh the entire database, or better still reload the SQL server.

Comment: Yes, it worked. Yet, i selected SMor's answer because this may be suffisant to solve my problem, but thanks